# Concurrency Visualizer unable to see custom ETW event

Tags: visual-studio-2013, etw, etw-eventsource

I have a custom EventSource that I am using to log an ETW event:

```
[EventSource(Name = "MyEventSource")]
public class MyEventSource : EventSource
{
    [Event(1, Message = "Test", Level = EventLevel.Informational)]
    public void Run(long fundId, DateTime date)
    {
        if (IsEnabled()) WriteEvent(1, fundId, date);
    }

    public static MyEventSource Log = new MyEventSource();
}
```

I have added my EventSource details to the Markers tab of the Advanced Settings dialog (from the Analyze menu in VS 2013) with it's correct Name and Procider GUID (I know these are correct as I can see the events in PerfView) and logging level = Everything.

When I run Concurrency Visualizer from Visual Studio I am unable to see my custom EventSource events though. However I can see other event sources (eg. some from the System.Collections.Concurrent provider)

Any help greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: I worked this out in the end - the DateTime type is not supported by EventSource - see http://entlib.codeplex.com/discussions/539531 for more info.

Comment: you should post this as answer and not as a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Here is he answer from *Zelestor*

> I worked this out in the end - the [DateTime type is not supported by
>   EventSource](http://entlib.codeplex.com/discussions/539531)